# How to upload NFT Metadata of multiple images after you get base-URI of folder using coding instead of manually doing it?

Tags: nft, ipfs, erc-1155, meta-data, pinata

How to upload NFT Metadata of multiple images after you get base-URI of folder using coding instead of manually doing it ?

So, After I upload my Image through Pinata/IPFS, I get a Base-URI. Now I want to create their metadata on the go using the BASE-URI/IPFS Hash. Using Code to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I got the opportunity of finding out the solution myself. You just have to upload the Images and Metadata in the same directory.